# Inverse of $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^{N}}r^i = x$

Tags: polynomials, inverse

I am looking to solve the following equation:

$$x = \sum_{i=1}^{N} r^i$$

I recognize that this is an order $N$ polynomial, which makes finding solutions hard for high $N$ (think of order $30$). Is there a way of solving a problem like this for $r$?

## Context

I am trying to deduce the interest $r$ from a $N$-year investment. Because of tax deductions etc I can only work with a (constant) yearly investment $B$ and the total sum at the end $T$.

The payoff $T$ could be found as follows:

$$T = \sum_{i=1}^N Br^i = B\sum_{i=1}^nr^i$$

Factoring out $B$ gets us:

$$ \frac{T}{B} = x = \sum_{i=1}^Nr^i$$

Which I'm trying to solve.

So I am looking at positive real values for both $x$ and $r$.

Because I'm working with interest rates, $r$ will be close to 1, so $x \sim N$.

Comment: Geometric series?

Comment: No, it is not possible to solve for $r$. You have to apply a numerical method.

Comment: Any context? And all solutions (real/complex) or one particular ?

Comment: This can be more or less doable depending on what assumptions might be able to be made. Are $x$ and $r$ expected to be real? Positive? Do we have any expectation about $x \ll N$, $x \sim N$, or $x \gg N$?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh Added context. Looking for positive real solutions

Comment: If $r=1+u$ with $u$ close to zero then the relation is $1+x=\frac{r^{N+1}-1}{r-1}=\frac{1}{u} ((1+u)^{N+1}-1) \sim (N+1) (1+u)^{N}$ from which you may deduce $u$. But this is a bad approximation for $u$ large (but then you may approximate differently). I don't think you can get a single expression that fits all relevant values of $r$.

Answer (score 3):

As you note, this is a fairly large polynomial in $r$, and so $r$ cannot be solved for in general (Abel-Ruffini theorem). We may, however, deduce some approximations.

For large $x$, we have

$$x\approx r^N\implies r\approx\sqrt[N]x$$

For small $x$, we have

$$x\approx r+r^2\implies r\approx\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{4x+1}}2$$

If $N$ is even, then we should consider both signs, if $N$ is odd, only consider the positive solution.

The full series expansion may be given by [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem),

$$r(x)=x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^kn^{(k)}a_{n,k}\\a_{n,k}=\begin{cases}B_{n-1,k}\left(\frac12,\frac13,\dots,\frac1{n-k+1}\right),&n-k<N\\B_{n-1,k}\big(\underbrace{\frac12,\frac13,\dots,\frac1N,0,\dots,0}_{n-k}\big),&n-k\ge N\end{cases}$$

where $B_{n,k}$ is a [Bell polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Reversion_of_series).

Comment: Say, does anyone know if the $k$th derivative of $(x^N-1)^n$ looks nice?